# How to style each thumbnail in react-grid-gallery component

Tags: reactjs, image-gallery

I'm trying to add styling to each of the thumbnails, I've been reading documentation and I think I was suppose to use "tumbnailStyle" attribute - but I have no idea how should I add className and to which property?

I did looked through the properties of the "this" object but didn't see anything I could attach my class to.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Gallery from "react-grid-gallery";
import "./wings.css";

let IMAGES = [];

class wings extends Component {
  state = {
    files: [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  };
  addToImages(files) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      IMAGES = [
        ...IMAGES,
        {
          src: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/gfx/" + files[i] + ".jpg",
          thumbnail:
            process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/gfx/" + files[i] + ".jpg",
          tags: [
          ],
          caption: ""
        }
      ];
    }
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addToImages(this.state.files);
  }
  styleSmall(param) {
    console.log(param); //how to style 


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container gallery-wrapper">
        <Gallery
          images={IMAGES}
          enableImageSelection={false}
          thumbnailStyle={this.styleSmall(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default wings;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thumbnailStyle` is a function that must be passed (not executed) and when called will return an object with css properties to be applied through `style` attribute, not class name.

So something like

```
<Gallery
      images={IMAGES}
      enableImageSelection={false}
      thumbnailStyle={this.styleSmall}
    />
```

where `styleSmall` is like

```
styleSmall(){
   return ({
      border:'5px solid red'
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a great skill to read documentation with understanding and often thats my problem!